# Shopify SKU Lookup using GraphQL

Tags: graphql, shopify, sku

I have a Query i have been using, but today i have noticed and issue
where the SKU appears to be searching a wild card opposed to just the SKU Field.
I suspect its the format of my query, as if i modify it slightly i can make it work correctly.

GraphQL Query:

```
query ($first: Int, $sku: String)
{ productVariants(first: $first, query: $sku) {
    edges {
      node {
        title
        id
        sku
        product {
          title
        }
        inventoryItem {
          id
          inventoryLevels(first: 3) {
            edges {
              node {
                id
                available
                location {
                  id
                  name
                  address {
                    city
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Variables

```
{
  "first": 5,  
  "sku": "555"
}
```

So when searching 555 SKU its actually returning products that have 555 in the body_html.

If i edit the query to have the SKU Embedded then it works, but i need to use it with a variable, maybe its my poorly formatted query.

Edited the Query as follow to embed the sku in the query and it works.

```
query ($first: Int)
{ productVariants(first: $first, query: "sku:555") {
    edges {
      node {
        title
        id
        sku
        product {
          title
        }
        inventoryItem {
          id
          inventoryLevels(first: 3) {
            edges {
              node {
                id
                available
                location {
                  id
                  name
                  address {
                    city
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How does one format it so it shows like:

```
 query: "sku:"$sku
```

Comment: I resolved this by editing the Variable (Essentially fudging it to include sku: )Unsure if there is a correct way to do this. {
  "first": 5,  
  "sku": "sku:555"
}

Comment: The correct form is query:"sku:'somesku''' so you note that your variable for the actual SKU string is enclosed in single-quotes to differentiate from the outer double-quotes.